# Xcode 10 doesn't compile dependencies

Tags: xcode, xcode9, xcode10, ios12

**Short summary:**
My app doesn't compile properly in Xcode10 if the project isn't cleaned before compilation, but works fine in Xcode9.

**Longer description:**
I have a static framework linked into my iOS app. Both projects are open in the same workspace and the framework is added to the app's "Embedded Binaries" in the project settings. However, changing code in the framework in Xcode10 does not trigger a compilation (not even with CMD+B), so the change doesn't appear when running the app. This was not an issue with Xcode9. The only workaround I've found so far is to clean the project every time before compiling, which causes abnormal compilation times and a lot of frustration.

Has anyone seen this issue and have a suggestion how to resolve it?

Comment: Did you  try to restart your Xcode (quit and open again) or even restart your Mac

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I've tried all that.

Comment: having the same issue when I change the code in my development pods, not an issue in xcode9

Comment: Come across the similar problem, dude, have you solve this problem? @Jonas

Comment: Yes, I found a workaround at least. There seems to be a lot of problems with the new build system introduced in Xcode 10. You can use the legacy build system by selecting File -> "Workspace settings..." and choose "Legacy Build System" in the dropdown, which solved the issues for me. Hopefully the issues are properly fixed in the next release of Xcode. Good luck! @suxinde2009

Comment: @Jonas Thanks for the update. It realy helps.

Comment: Xcode Version 10.1, released last couple of hours, fixed these issues for me. The new build system works properly in my case after the update. So the issue has been resolved!

Comment: For me nether Xcode 10.1 nor switching to legacy build system didn't fix anything. Also archive is failing with cause of framemork "No such file or directory" (but only with new build system)

Comment: On Xcode 10.2 , no joy

Comment: I'm encountering this in Xcode 12.2. One framework is built, but a sibling framework with all the same settings (as far as I can tell) is ignored. The same project worked fine in Xcode 12.1 and even the 12.2 beta.